# Flatten an array on bigquery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery and I have a table with nested fields which I need to flatten in order to be able to download the table.
I found explanation page (https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/how-tos/flatten-bigquery-table) but I don't understand it fully.

Here's the code:

standardSQL

```
SELECT
      reference_name, start_position, end_position, reference_bases,
      call.name AS call_name
FROM
      `PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE` AS t,
      t.call AS call
```

I understand why we would write "call.name AS call_name". But what I don't understand why we write "t.call AS call"?  What does the letter "t" stand for here? Why do we write t.call? Why do we need need to create an alias with "AS call"?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what I don't understand why we write "t.call AS call"? What does the letter "t" stand for here? Why do we write t.call?

Letter `t` is the alias for table in above row. In `t.call` it fully qualifies path to `call` inner table - call is repeated field so along with `t` it is treated as a 'virtual' table that you can use in joins - in this case it is CROSS JOIN (as comma is a shortcut to CROSS JOIN)

> Why do we need need to create an alias with "AS call"?

In SELECT statement there is a reference to call.name which means that you output name field from that call 'virtual table'. This is important in cases when there is another name column let's say in main table, so you avoid ambiguity error
Note: if there is no any other column named name - you can skip call as in below example

```
SELECT
      reference_name, start_position, end_position, reference_bases,
      name AS call_name
FROM
      `PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE` AS t,
      t.call
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, that makes much more sense now. Thanks so much!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm baffled.  "Flattening" refers to fields that are repeated -- arrays.  You use `unnest` to flatten them.  That would be:

```
SELECT reference_name, start_position, end_position, reference_bases,
       call.name AS call_name
FROM `PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE` t CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(t.calls) AS call
```

This says that:

- `calls` is a repeated field in your table.
- `calls` is a struct.
- `calls` has a column called `name`.

I renamed the `call` column `calls` because it contains multiple values -- and to distinguish it from `call` in the `FROM` clause.

The name column is being returned in the outer query.

Here is an example you can run:

```
with `PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE` as (
       select 'a' as reference_name, 1 as start_position, 5 as end_position, 'b' as reference_bases,
              array[struct('name1' as name),
                    struct('name2' as name),
                    struct('name3' as name)
                   ] calls                   
      )
SELECT reference_name, start_position, end_position, reference_bases,
       call.name AS call_name
FROM `PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE` t CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(t.calls) AS call;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, my SQL skills are still quite basic and sometimes I come across tasks which require knowledge that surpasses them. I can imagine my questions can be baffling for advanced SQL users but you have no idea how helpful this is. Thank you so much for having taken the time!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AndyRojas . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi Gordon, both answers shed light on my issue and complemented each other. I tried to choose both but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/how-tos/flatten-bigquery-table&ved=2ahUKEwjFivabn6HqAhXgILcAHcw_D3gQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw054gXKaAdlbah90H2t5KyW).

You can achieve this using unnest:

```sql
SELECT
  reference_name, start_position, end_position, reference_bases,
  call.name AS call_name
FROM
  `PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE`,
  UNNEST(call) AS call
```